# what is best practice for SSL when redirecting an entire domain to new site?

Tags: redirect, ssl

When redirecting an entire site to another domain,

https:Site-X.com >> 301 Redirect to >> Https:Site-Y.com

do you have to maintain the SSL certificate for site X?

The SSL expires 3 days before the planned redirect, would moving the redirect up let allow us to let the SSL expire?

Comment: Do you know if you can request a SAN Certificate? You could deploy the same cert to both sites.

Comment: This sounds like web development/cert questions and has nothing to do with code itself. This belongs on another site in the network and is off topic here.

Comment: Yes, you will need to maintain a valid certificate for Site-X.com for browsers to first connect to it and then get redirected. If there isn't one, browsers will show the invalid certificate page.